# Can not set stop action on AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
 SESReceiptRule1:
  Type: AWS::SES::ReceiptRule
  Properties:
    RuleSetName: !Ref ReceiptRuleSet
    Rule:
      Name: !Ref ReceiptRuleName1
      Enabled: true
      Recipients:
      - !Sub administrator@${DomainNamePublic}
      - !Sub postmaster@${DomainNamePublic}
      - !Sub webmaster@${DomainNamePublic}
      ScanEnabled: true
      TlsPolicy: !Ref TlsPolicy
      Actions:
      - SNSAction:
          TopicArn: !Ref ValidationEmailTopic
          Encoding: UTF-8
      - StopAction:
          Scope: RuleSet
          TopicArn: !Ref ValidationEmailTopic
```

but when I try to launch it I get the following error message:

Stop action, if any, must be placed at the end of the actions list (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 943f1401-f18b-11e8-95c1-4b550d223892)

Comment: Up ! did you find any answer ?

Comment: yes, I did;  just removed the TopicARN, then it worked.